# option to promote to top of list in drupal

Tags: views, nodes

I have a site that shows top music in a list, I have created a content type called "topMusic" and a view that will show all topMusic content types.

this View shows topMusic content in a row, first content created will get on top of the list, anything added after that will show below it.

I want to add a new button or trigger to the content type, that when its "on", this content gets on the top of the list.

Any idea's will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, you will find a checkbox on every node-edit form called "Sticky at top of lists". It's under the "Publishing options". If you use that to identify the top content, you can add a sort criterion "Node: Sticky" (descending) to your view to make the selected nodes appear on top.

If you need even more control (ie. you want to specify the exact order) use a module like [Draggable Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) or [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue).

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you mean, but You can use view's built-in filter system to change the order of the display. The default is creation time hence you got "first content created will get on top of the list, anything added after that will show below it."